# How to type match and unwrap optional values in a switch statement (simultaneously)?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Is there a way to combine type matching and unwrapping optional values within a case?

In the following playground code there are three loops:

**Loop A** is using `if let` to match the type and unwrap the optional values at the same time.

In **Loop B** I replaced the `if let`'s with a `switch` statement. However I'm using `where` and check against `nil`, and then force unwrap my values from this point forward.

I'd like to know if there is a way similar to **Loop C** to unwrap the values so that I can use those new non optional variables the way I do in Loop A.

```
import Foundation

// Setup
protocol MyObjects {}

struct MyTopic: MyObjects {
    let name: String?
}

struct MyQuestion: MyObjects {
    let text: String?
    let topic: String?
}

let topicOrQuestions: [MyObjects] = [
    MyQuestion(text: "questionA", topic: "topicA"),
    MyTopic(name: "topicA"),
    MyTopic(name: "topicB"),
    MyTopic(name: nil)
]

// Loop A:
for topicOrQuestion in topicOrQuestions {
    if let name = (topicOrQuestion as? MyTopic)?.name {
        print(name)
    } else if let text = (topicOrQuestion as? MyQuestion)?.text, let topic = (topicOrQuestion as? MyQuestion)?.topic {
        print(text, topic)
    } else {
        print("Error: wrong type or nil value")
    }
}

// Loop B:
for topicOrQuestion in topicOrQuestions {

    switch topicOrQuestion {
    case let topic as MyTopic where topic.name != nil:
        print(topic.name!)
    case let question as MyQuestion where question.text != nil && question.topic != nil:
        print(question.text!, question.topic!)
    default:
        print("Error: wrong type or nil value")
    }
}

// Loop C (doesn't work):
for topicOrQuestion in topicOrQuestions {

    switch topicOrQuestion {
    case let name as MyTopic.name: // <-- Is it possible to unwrap the values here directly similar to the if let's in Loop A?
        print(name)
    case let text as MyQuestion.text, let topic as MyQuestion.topic:
        print(text, topic)
    default:
        print("Error: wrong type or nil value")
    }
}

/*
Current output from Loop A and B and expected output from Loop C:

questionA topicA
topicA
topicB
Error: wrong type or nil value
*/
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `protocol MyObjects {}` ?

Comment: In my example it doesn't have a purpose other than giving the array a type, the array could also just be [Any] instead. : )

Comment: Well in my answer I used `MyObjects` as a base too, but I don't like having empty protocols and IMHO it's a code smell. You could probably refactor your code to avoid having to rely on such a trick but it's probably for another question

Comment: In my actual app I'm using the protocol as a type in different places like I would with a superclass. It doesn't really add too much to my example though, you are right. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to cast and unwrap in a case, but with this extension at least your `Loop A` would be less verbose:

```
extension MyObjects {
    subscript<T: MyObjects, V>(topicOrQuestion keypath: (T) -> V) -> V? {
        get {
            guard let root = self as? T else { return nil }
            return keypath(root)
        }
    }
}
```

you can also write this loop:

```
for topicOrQuestion in topicOrQuestions {

    if let topicName = topicOrQuestion[topicOrQuestion: \MyTopic.name] as? String  {
        print(topicName)
    }
    if let questionText = topicOrQuestion[topicOrQuestion: \MyQuestion.text] as? String ,
       let questionTopic = topicOrQuestion[topicOrQuestion: \MyQuestion.topic] as? String {
        print(questionText, questionTopic)
    }
}
// questionA topicA
// topicA
// topicB
```

Comment: How would you use that in a switch statement?

Comment: I wouldn't use a `switch` statement at all with your data model. I would certainly not introduce a empty protocol just to be able to use a `switch`. Maybe there's another, less verbose solution for your problem but you need to provide more details

Comment: Okay, you already mentioned your opinion about the protocol, however as mentioned above in my comments you can basically ignore them and just assume an array of [Any]. However my question asked for the use of a switch statement. I'd appreciate an answer to that if you can.

Comment: Again, "I don't think you will be able to cast and unwrap in a case" but hey! maybe I'm wrong, good luck and have fun!

Comment: I didn't see you changed your answer and only read your comment. My mistake. Okay if you think it's not possible then that's an answer I can live with.

Comment: No problem, FYI I tried to play with the pattern matching operator `~=` to no avail. I think with more details about what you're trying to do it should be possible to find the right way to do what you want. But we don't know why `MyTopic.name` is `optional` and how your code should be used. you're only using `print` in your example. if you need a string representation, maybe `CustomStringConvertible` can help you. but again, if you can, you should try to be more specific

Comment: I'll see if I can provide a bit more info to my question. Just to give you some idea, in my app the topicOrQuestions array is an array of synced Realm elements, and the structs are  Realm objects.  Where the print statements are in the example I'm turning the Realm Objects into the corresponding Objects that I'm using throughout my app and are required by my DatabaseService protocol methods.

Comment: In that case I tend to use `associatedtypes` but this has broader implications and it may not be a good idea for you

Comment: I'll stick with the solution similar to Loop A or Loop B for now. After more research and trying all sorts of things I must agree, it doesn't seem to be possible to do both of those things, therefore marked your answer as correct. I'll look into associatedtypes for my specific use case.